How do I use both `require` and `import` in a Node.js script?
having a node js basic project setup with package.json , install a package and try to use both require and import statment in the same file; to do that here is what did so far but not working.
First Trial
// package.json (v1)
{
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@xkeshav/day": "latest"
  }
}

and called as below
// src/index.js
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");
console.log({ oneDay });
console.log("Hello from template repository");

above works fine

now changes from require to import statament
import { oneDay } from "@xkeshav/day";
console.log({ oneDay });

and when run the file, it throws error
(node:14233) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/recursive/dev/template/src/index.js:1
import { oneDay } from "@xkeshav/day";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

highlight

add type:"module" in package.json

so added as below
// package.json ( v2 )
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@xkeshav/day": "latest"
  }
}

and now this works.

now removed import statment and added require statment
const { oneDay } =  require("@xkeshav/day");
console.log({ oneDay });

and run the file ; it throws error
at /src/index.js:1
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");
                   ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/recursive/dev/template/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

hightlight is

package.json contains "type": "module", To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

so rename index.js  to index.cjs and make changes in package.json also
// package.json ( v3 )
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.cjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.cjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@xkeshav/day": "latest"
  }
}

this works.

import and require together
now addd the import statement along with require as below
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");

import { oneDay as dayOne } from "@xkeshav/day";

console.log({ oneDay, dayOne });
console.log("Hello from template repository");

and when run the file; it throws error
(node:14757) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
at src/index.cjs:3
import { oneDay as dayOne } from "@xkeshav/day";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module


Highlight

set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension

so rename index.cjs to index.mjs and run in package.json also
 // # package.json ( v4 )
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.cjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@xkeshav/day": "latest"
  }
}

now gives another error

> @xkeshav/template@0.0.3 start
> node src/index.mjs
at src/index.mjs:1
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");
                   ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

so how can we use both kind of syntax in same file? and what that file extension would be '.mjs' or '.cjs' or '.js` and any changes in package.json required ?

Node does not support this. You could try a different runtime.

"import and require together" - why would you want to do that? Don't write code like this!

just trying something and I have seen some pages have require and import both ; here I am adding same package but sometimes different package which are not available in import

Have you read the docs? They point out a solution.

"I have seen some pages have require and import both" - can you link those? And why did they do this?

Thanks for the docs link but that syntax does not work in js file ; Do I need to change file extension for that agin?

I have seen in some codebase; does not remember but hereis link just I googled: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/lessons-from-open-source-can-you-use-require-import-same-narasinga-rgo8e/ ; it might be wrong but cant we use require and import togethr at all ?

@xkeshav So can you do it? Yes. Is it a good idea? Definitely not. Still, how do they do it? By using a transpiler (webpack) that rewrites both forms to commonjs require before the code is executed. Also, next.js specifically appears to jump through some hoops to make sure it can both be imported (in an esm project) and required (in a commonjs project), but that doesn't mean it's a good practice.

Thanks. I got you. but can we keep .mjs file in code and use import only ? does that a good way to write or keep stick with type and .js thing

I don't think there's a clear convention or popularity winner. Both work. Depending on your situation (e.g. a script file where you don't want to carry an extra package.json around vs a library that declares its preferred module system) one might be more appropriate than the other; if both work for you, choose either.

To use both require and import in the same file, you need to handle them based on whether you're using CommonJS or ES Modules:
Option 1: CommonJS (.cjs file)

Use require as usual.
For import, use dynamic import syntax:

// src/index.cjs
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");

(async () => {
  const { oneDay: dayOne } = await import("@xkeshav/day");
  console.log({ oneDay, dayOne });
})();

In package.json, set "type": "commonjs".
Option 2: ES Module (.mjs file)

Use import as usual.
For require, use createRequire:

// src/index.mjs
import { oneDay as dayOne } from "@xkeshav/day";
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const { oneDay } = require("@xkeshav/day");

console.log({ oneDay, dayOne });

In package.json, set "type": "module".
Which to Use?

Use .cjs if you prefer CommonJS (require).
Use .mjs if you prefer ES Modules (import).

This way, you can mix require and import in the same file.
